# Giphy not working on Discord bot (javascript)

Tags: javascript, discord.js, giphy-api

I was following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=We2ijSkByw0) tutorial on how to make a discord bot, everything was working fine until 33:32 where he added the giphy stuff i had already installed giphy sdk/api, created an application, but after he made the search statement he said you can console log it so i did it, and there were some gif results coming out, which returned undefined on my console(i dunno why), then he added some math stuff, which i also did, then at the point where he added the messaging part where he also added this code `files:[responseFinal.images.fixed_height.url]` which then returned this on my console

```
(node:3136) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'images' of undefined
    at D:\Discord bots\Oboto v2.0\index.js:24:61
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:3136) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:3136) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

and this confused the flip outta me, then i picked an alt approach, instead of doing `giphy.search` i did
`giphy.random` with the same arguments, removed the math stuff and `console.log(response)`the response and guess what it actually gave me a single gif!(in the console of course) then i implemented to my `files:[]`statement aaaaand it returned the same thing (`cannot read property 'images' of undefined`)  im also kinda new to discord.js and javascript, also here is my entire code,

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token, giphyToken } = require('./config.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();

var GphApiClient = require('giphy-js-sdk-core')
giphy = GphApiClient(giphyToken)

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.member.hasPermission(["KICK_MEMBERS", "BAN_MEMBERS"])){

        if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}kick`)) {

            let member = message.mentions.members.first();
            member.kick().then((member) =>{

                giphy.random('gifs', {'q':'fail'})  
                    .then((response) => {

                        console.log(response);
                        message.channel.send(":wave:",{files:[response.images.fixed_height.url]});

                })


            })
        }   
    }
})

client.login(token);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cannot read property 'images' of undefined`, this means you are trying to access a null object. Same as null pointer exception in java. It means your response is null.

And you are also getting `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` which means your promise is throwing error which you are not catching anywhere. You can catch your error like this

```
member.kick().then((member) =>{
    giphy.random('gifs', {'q':'fail'})  
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        message.channel.send(":wave:",{files:[response.images.fixed_height.url]});
    }).catch(e => { console.error(e}) }
}).catch(e => { console.error(e) }
```

Now you can see what error you are getting. You can also use try catch approach with async await.

Answer (score 0):

THIS CODE IS FIXED BY ME :D

## Discord Bot - Kick member with Giphy

IM NOT A PROFESSIONAL AT ALL.
You can also add this giphy to new member notice.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token, giphyToken } = require('./config.json');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

var GphApiClient = require('giphy-js-sdk-core');
bot.giphy = GphApiClient(giphyToken);

bot.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.member.hasPermission(['KICK_MEMBER', 'BAN_MEMBERS'])) {
    //console.log(message.content);

    if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}kick`)) {
      //message.channel.send("kick")

      let member = message.mentions.members.first();
      member.kick().then((member) => {
        bot.giphy.search('gifs', { q: 'fail' }).then((response) => {
            var totalResponses = response.data.length;
            var responseIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1) % totalResponses;
            var responseFinal = response.data[responseIndex];

            message.channel.send(':wave: ' + member.displayName + ' has been kicked!',{
                files: [responseFinal.images.fixed_height.url]
              }
            )
          })
      })
    }
  }
});

bot.login(token);
```

Comment: i am just a newbie after all